# sum of coefficients of polynomial?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $\sqrt{2+(\sqrt3 +\sqrt5)}$ is root of polynomial of eighth degree then, the sum of absolute values of coefficients of polynomial is?

I found this question on https://brilliant.org/assessment/s/algebra-and-number-theory/1974729/
I want to know is there any simple way to solve it?

Comment: If $a$ is a root of $p(x)=0$ then it is also a root of $q(x)=\alpha p(x)=0$ for any $\alpha$. I assume the question states that the polynomial is monic - the coefficient of the highest power of $x$ is $1$.

Comment: @Phani Raj Note that solutions are posted on Wednesday/Thursday of the week after.

Comment: The question was misquoted (since this is from a brilliant.org problem). We restricted them to monic polynomials with integer coefficients. We further asked only for the sum of absolute values of coefficients apart from the monic leading term.

Comment: @Phani Raj Note that the link which you provided is unique to yourself. You need to use the "share this problem" link, in order for others to see. For example, this [link](https://brilliant.org/i/AKk2ij/) works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call your number $x$. That means that we have the relation $x = \sqrt{2+(\sqrt3 +\sqrt5)}$

It follows by squaring both sides that $x^2 - 2 = \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}$. Further squaring and subtracting leftover integers yields
$$
((x^2 - 2)^2 - 8)^2 - 60 = 0
$$
and you have your polynomial. Now all you need to do is multiply out the parentheses, and you're more or less there.

Note that to get a unique answer, we have to require the polynomial to be *monic*. I assume that this is the case.

Comment: Can you explain why the answer is not unique if the polynomial is not monic?

Comment: Because then the same number would also be a root of for instance the polynomial $5(((x^2 - 2)^2 - 8)^2 - 60)$, which has a very different sum of coefficients. Also, there is nothing special about $5$ in this case. Any non-zero number gives a different polynomial, with different sums of coefficients, but the same roots.

Comment: You also need the polynomial to have only integer or rational coefficients. Otherwise the following polynomial is also valid.$$x^8-\sqrt{2+(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{5})}x^7$$

Comment: @MilindHegde Yes, monic with integer coefficients. In the comments, I have provided an accurate link to the actual problem as stated.